# jQuery select my input tag above

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

When a user click on my `icon-calendar` inside the `i` tag I would like to reference the input just above.

```
<div class="input-control text">
    <input type="text" data-bind="text: fromDate" />
    <i data-bind="datepicker: fromDate" class="icon-calendar btn"></i>
</div>
```

So how to use jQuery to select the `input` above my `i` tag.

Something like:

```
$(element).closest('input')
```

Where element is my `i` tag clicked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

```
$(element).prev("input").first();
```

Answer (score 0):

[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree not the siblings of your element, you can use [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$('.btn').siblings('input').data('bind')
$('.btn').prev().data('bind')
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TX7vK/)